# How to use SMTP in Google Application Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, smtp, office365

I need to send emails with attachments from my GAS web application. The client is using `smtp.office365.com`. Is that possible to use such SMTP?

**Question1:** Can I somehow use perhaps gmail alias `GmailApp.sendEmail('to@email.com', 'subject', 'message', {'from':'aliasinmyGmailaccount@office365.com'})`

**Question2:** If I am able to use alias then does such sending of emails count against daily quota.

**Question3:** is it possible to use SMTP server in GAS application?

Comment: I think that's something that you have to accomplish in gmail setup to create an appropriate alias.  Once you have the alias created and  verified then you an use it in google apps script.

Comment: AFAIK google apps script doesn't get involved in the email protocol.  How the email is sent is determined by how you setup the account.

Comment: @Cooper I was think of using alias and then send the email but I am not sure if I can set up alias for office365 but more importantly I need to know if the 100 emails a day applies for alias email too. Would you know?

Comment: You can indeed send an email from an alias - however I am not sure I understand: do you want the address to be an alias of an office365 address? As for the quota, as long as you are using `GmailApp` the respective quotas are still applied.

Comment: @ale13 yes, I want the from address be an "office36" address. Thank you for the quota answer.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: Yes, use alias with you code

Q2: Yes, for example, 100 recipients every 24 hours

Q3: Normally no. May be there is workable library.

Comment: I thought that the answers would be like that but I wanted to make sure because production environment might not need only 100 emails a day.

Comment: So, you are looking for alternatives? May be `nodemailer` (node.js) is what you are looking for.

Comment: can I use nodemailer in GAS? I cannot see how. Currently the only option seems to me to use POST call to a SMTP service like TurboSMTP

Comment: Probably no for GAS. But you could try if it work on web apps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create an alias for this, you can POST using [`UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) to an external email service that has an API.

There are a number of providers with free plans if you don't send many emails (although these free plans rarely allow you to pass SPF/DMARC, so it may be worth upgrading).

Try something like this (obviously will vary depending on your provider):

```js
const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.example.com/email';
const FROM_ADDRESS = 'from@example.com';
const API_TOKEN = 'YOUR_API_TOKEN';

let emailAddress = 'to@example.com';

let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
  API_ENDPOINT,
  {
    'method': 'post',
    'headers': {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Basic: ${API_TOKEN}`,
    },
    'payload': JSON.stringify({
      'From': FROM_ADDRESS,
      'To': emailAddress,
      'Subject': 'POSTing email from Google Scripts',
      'TextBody': 'You have succesfully POSTed email Google Scripts',
    })
  }
);
console.log(response.getContentText());
```

Answer (score 0):

*To address your questions:*

You will have to create an alias for this. The best solution for this is to follow the steps in this article [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370).

Therefore, as long as the address on behalf of whom you want to send the email is indeed an alias, then you won't encounter any issues using the `from` with `GmailApp` / `MailApp`.

Unfortunately, these emails *do count* against your daily quota as the `from:email` is an alias of your account. So depending on the account that you posses, it's best to check the current quotas available at this link [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas).

Also, there is no way to integrate SMTP with Apps Script directly as the use of other libraries /  third party tools might be required. Nonetheles, you may benefit from checking the Python and PHP samples documented [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-libraries).

#### Reference

- [Set an Email Alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370);
- [Apps Script Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas);
- [IMAP Libraries and Samples](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-libraries).