# Using bluehost to send confirmation email on google form submit

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I want to send a confirmation email whenever a customer submit a booking via google form. The content of the email will be partly based on the number of people and timeslot the customer chosen. I can do it with Gmail.

Sorry for my explanation. Let me rephrase the following.

I subscribed to bluehost "CHOICE PLUS" service which allows me to have my own domain and my own email. Let's say my company email is "info@mycompanyname.com". The email quota I can send with bluehost is 150 email per hours which can satisfy my need.

I would like to send the email confirmation upon new response on a google form from this mailbox "info@mycompanyname.com", not with the Gmail account that owns the google form and relevant script (which I currently do with 100 email daily quota only)

Please refer to the plan below
https://www.bluehost.com/pricing

How can I do that? Below is the script for me to send from Gmail whenever a response is submitted.

```
function sendBookingConfirmationEmail(e) {

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("confirmationEmail.html");
  var emailTo = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  var bookingParameters = e.response.getItemResponses();

  var bookingName = bookingParameters[0].getResponse()
  var numberOfTele = bookingParameters[1].getResponse()
  var numberOfKids = bookingParameters[2].getResponse()
  var numberOfAdults = bookingParameters[3].getResponse()
  var scheduledSlot = bookingParameters[4].getResponse()

  html.numberOfKids = numberOfKids;
  html.numberOfAdults = numberOfAdults;
  html.numberOfTele = numberOfTele;
  html.scheduledSlot = scheduledSlot;

  var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();

  var emailSubject = "BOOKING CONFIRMATION";
  var options = { htmlBody: htmlText }

  if (emailTo !== undefined) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, emailSubject, "", options);

  }

}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>  <?= numberOfKids ?> <?= numberOfAdults ?> Your booking has been confirmed.  etc...</p>

    <p> Best Regards<br>
    Team</p>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I would like to send the confirmation from my company email which is hosted by bluehost instead so that I can send 150 emails per hour.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have rephrased the question. Please kindly review again

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, I'm worried that even when your expected email address as an email alias is used, the quotas of Gmail cannot be avoided. Although, unfortunately, I cannot know the detail of your expected email server, in this case, for example, when the email server you want to use has the API for sending the email, how about using it? If this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: would it be easier if I have a Microsoft 365 business basic which comes with a business email? the quota for microsoft email server seems to be 10,000 recipients per day and 30 message per min. Also can do. I think microsoft should have API that I could use to call function from app script?

Comment: if you use an Apps Script service, you have the Apps Script quotas. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68653587/3410584. If Bluehost has an API to send email (like Mailchimp or Sendgrid), then you could make an API call with Urlfetch to tell the other provider to send an email. But if you use GmailApp you use Gmail as "email sender" (and then have GMail quotas), if you use MailApp you use Apps Script as "email sender" and then have Apps Script quotas.

Comment: Do you mean even if I can make an API call to tell Microsoft exchange server to send email, it will still be subjected to daily quota imposed by apps script , which is 100 mail per day for free account?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that the discussion has already been advanced. In this case, I would like to respect the existing discussion.