# Send Email using SMTP Relay with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my first time dealing with SMTP-Relay to send the notification email.

We want to avoid the quota limit from 2,000 to 10,000 emails per day using smtp-relay. Is there anyone that has already used this?

Please let me know how to use it on Google Apps Script. I've been searching through the documentation but there aren't any examples.


This is the code example that I've found, but it still gets in the 2,000 quota limit

```
function myFunction() {
  var smtpUsername = '';
  var smtpPassword = '';
  var smtpServer = 'smtp-relay.gmail.com';
  var smtpPort = 587;

  var recipient = '';
  var subject = '';
  var body = '';

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipient,
    subject: subject,
    body: body,
    smtpServers: smtpServer,
    smtpPort: smtpPort,
    smtpUsername: smtpUsername,
    smtpPassword: smtpPassword,
    replyTo: smtpUsername
  });

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68558179/how-to-use-smtp-in-google-application-script

Comment: I've already added a code example

Comment: What kind of account do you have?

Comment: @Tedinoz Enterprise